# Best practices to manage state and API fetching in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React for the first time and just shipped my first app.

The app is mounted on a single page in a node/express dashboard app which uses server-side templates. My plan is to gradually extend the React app to replace additional templates within the dashboard.

Everything works, but I have two issues:

1. There is already quite a lot of state, and the code is filled with props being passed down to components. I feel like this would make the code unmaintainable as the app grows.
2. The code for communicating with the back-end API is not very declarative. I am manually indicating when to refetch from the API, to prevent double fetching on initial load.

I am looking for advice on best practices in React to handle these two issues. The code showing both issues is provided below.

---

**Questions**

1. What would be the best way for me to manage state in this app as the complexity grows? Would it for example be:

- Create objects for the useState hook instead of primitives and pass those down?
- Use [component composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) to reduce the prop drilling?
- Use React Context?
- Use Redux?

2. Is there a more declarative way of achieving what I am currently doing sync the state with the API?

I am manually disabling fetching initially because the initial query parameters are included in the first object returned from the API but they are not included in the url. So I want to build them when initialising the app without refetching.

---

**Code and stack**

I included the main part of the code for the app below, as well as the file tree for the project to give an idea of the structure.

Stack details:

- TypeScript
- Vite.js for dev-server and builds
- SWR for data-fetching
- Express.js backend with cookie-session for sessions and persistent query parameters

**/src/Feedback.txs** - holds the state and fetches data accordingly

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

import { getActiveTeamID, getTimescaleValue } from "./lib/util";

import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import Body from "./components/feedback/Body";

export default function Feedback() {
  // API
  const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useState("");
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/client/feedback${queryParams}`);

  // Local state
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Feedback");
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState("is");
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  const [activeTeamID, setActiveTeamID] = useState(0);
  const [showChildren, setShowChildren] = useState(true);
  const [timescale, setTimescale] = useState("last-3");
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [isDummy, setIsDummy] = useState(false);

  // Trigger for refetching
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(false);
  const [pageChange, setPageChange] = useState(false);

  const isLoading = !error && !data;

  // Determine initial state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setLng(data.client.lng);
      setTitle(data.client.title);
      setTeams(data.filters.teams);
      setIsDummy(data.filters.dummy);
      setActiveTeamID(getActiveTeamID(data.filters.teams));
      setShowChildren(data.filters.children);
      setTimescale(getTimescaleValue(data.filters.timescale.selected));
      document.title = `${data.client.title}`;
    }
  }, [data]);

  // Refetch from API
  useEffect(() => {
    if (refetch) {
      const pageNoToUse = pageChange ? page : 1;
      setQueryParams(
        `?team=${activeTeamID}&children=${showChildren}&view=${timescale}&search=${searchTerm}&page=${pageNoToUse}`
      );
    }
    setPageChange(false);
    setRefetch(false);
  }, [refetch]);

  if (error) {
    return <div>{error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header
        title={title}
        lng={lng}
        filters={data?.filters}
        translate={translate}
        setTranslate={setTranslate}
        setQueryParams={setQueryParams}
        teams={teams}
        setTeams={setTeams}
        activeTeamID={activeTeamID}
        setActiveTeamID={setActiveTeamID}
        showChildren={showChildren}
        setShowChildren={setShowChildren}
        timescale={timescale}
        setTimescale={setTimescale}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
        setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
        setRefetch={setRefetch}
      />
      <Body
        feedback={data?.feedback}
        lng={lng}
        translate={translate}
        page={page}
        setPage={setPage}
        pagination={data?.pagination}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        setRefetch={setRefetch}
        setPageChange={setPageChange}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
        setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
        isDummy={isDummy}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**/src/main.txs** - this is the entry point to the app

```
import "vite/modulepreload-polyfill";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Feedback from "./Feedback";
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import fetcher from "./lib/util/fetcher";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fetcher: fetcher,
      }}
    >
      <Feedback />
    </SWRConfig>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**File tree**

```
client
┣ dist
┃ ┣ assets
┃ ┃ ┗ main.b889a7af.js
┃ ┗ manifest.json
┣ node_modules
┃ ┣ ...
┣ src
┃ ┣ components
┃ ┃ ┣ feedback
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ chat
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ CommentEmployee.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ CommentInitial.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ CommentManager.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Footer.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Panel.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ PanelContent.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Body.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Card.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Pagination.tsx
┃ ┃ ┣ header
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ filters
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ ActiveButtons.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ ChildrenFilter.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Filters.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ TeamFilter.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ other
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ DownloadExcel.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Search.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Title.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Translations.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ timescale
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ SubmenuRange.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ SubmenuSurvey.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Timescale.tsx
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Header.tsx
┃ ┣ lib
┃ ┃ ┣ util
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ classnames.ts
┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ fetcher.ts
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
┃ ┃ ┗ translate.ts
┃ ┣ Feedback.tsx
┃ ┣ main.tsx
┃ ┗ vite-env.d.ts
┣ .eslintrc.json
┣ package-lock.json
┣ package.json
┣ tsconfig.json
┣ tsconfig.node.json
┗ vite.config.ts
```